# How to save info from java into a mysql database

Tags: java, bots, irc

I am currently coding a bot for a fun java project and I am making a warn system. The current problem I am having is that everytime I restart the bot the data inputted gets lost. I have searched for 5 days now trying to get this to work. Please help!

```
//warn_command
    if(message.startsWith("!warn") || message.startsWith("!Warn")) {
        String[] command = message.split(" ");
        String warn_target = command[1];
        String warn_reason = "";

        //admin/op_target checker
        for(String admin: adminList) {
            if(warn_target.equals(admin)) {
                target_a_bool = true;
            } else {
                target_a_bool = false;
            }
        }
        for(String op: opList) {
            if(warn_target.equals(op)) {
                target_o_bool = true;
            } else {
                target_o_bool = false;
            }
        }
        //end_admin/op_target checker

        for(int i = 2; i < command.length; i++) {
            warn_reason += command[i];
            if (i != (command.length - 1)) {
                warn_reason += " ";
            }
        }
        if(target_a_bool == true) {
            sendMessage(channel, "This user cannot be warned");
            target_a_bool = false;

        } else if(target_o_bool == true) {
            if(sender_a_bool == true) {

                sendMessage(channel, sender + " has warned " + warn_target + " for reason " + warn_reason);
                warn_list.add("User Warned: " + warn_target + " | Reason Warned: " + warn_reason + " | Warned by: " + sender);
                sender_a_bool = false;

            } else {

                sendMessage(channel, "This user cannot be warned");

            } target_o_bool = false;
        } else {

            sendMessage(channel, sender + " has warned " + warn_target + " for reason " + warn_reason);
            warn_list.add("User Warned: " + warn_target + " | Reason Warned: " + warn_reason + " | Warned by: " + sender);

        }
    }
    //end_warn_command

    //warn_checker
    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!w list")) {
        for(int i = 0; i < warn_list.size(); i++) {
            if(i != warn_list.size()) {
                String warnlist = warn_list.toString();
                sendMessage(channel, warnlist);
            }

        }
    }
    //end_warn_checker`

    //warn_list_clearer
    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!c warnlist")) {
        if(sender_a_bool == true) {
            warn_list.clear();
            sendMessage(channel, sender + " has cleared the warn list!");
            sender_a_bool = false;

        }
    }
    //end_warn_list_clearer
```

All the booleans and arrays are predefined in the config part of the bot. All this code is currently functional, it is just every time I restart the bot all the info stored in the arrays gets deleted.

EDIT: I would like this to be connected to a mysql database that I am using with phpMyAdmin. Is this at all possible.

Comment: this would be the same with any program of any sort. data is stored in RAM and ceases to exist when the program exits. The solution is to use persistent storage, e.g. files on disk, database etc. etc.

Comment: ADyson, do you have any clue how to make a SQL database and would you be willing to help?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of tutorials online showing how to create databases and use SQL. I don't think I need to add my own attempt to the mix. P.S. Just small correction: Your edit says "hosting via phpMyAdmin". That's not quite accurate. MySQL runs as a service on your machine. phpMyAdmin is just one of many user interfaces which gives you a window into your database. There are lots of others, graphical and command-line based, plus anyone can write their own in most programming languages.

Comment: ADyson, thanks for the input. I have used MySQL databases in a website that was coded in HTML5 and php, will it be similar to that or no?

Comment: very similar. except that you need to use Java's MySQL libraries in order to give instructions to the database instead of PHP's. The SQL syntax and everything else is identical.

Comment: ADyson, to connect i need to know the host, where would I find the host for the database when using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: this kind of thing is not directly related to phpMyAdmin, that's just a GUI. Is your database installed on your own machine, or hosted by an external service? The top bar in phpMyAdmin (depending on version) might say something like "Server: localhost:3306". In which case, "localhost" would be the hostname, and 3306 the port number. But that's relative - if phpMyAdmin is installed on the same machine as the mySQL service, then localhost is sufficient, hence why it reports that. If your Java app is on a different machine than mySQL, you need to know the real hostname or IP of the mySQL machine.

Comment: ADyson, they are both hosted off the same machine

Comment: ADyson, what would I put for the quoted part? Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",
                         username,
                         password);

Comment: to be honest I don't know, I'm not a Java expert (10 years ago I might have been). You can look up the format of connection strings in a few places online though.

Comment: ADyson, you know anyone who might know?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jdbc%20connection%20string%20example%20mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data*Stream to write and read the values. Since you didnt show your variables, i'll use a sample:

```
  boolean[] ab = new boolean[5];
  boolean b = false;

  // write
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myconfig.data");
  DataOutputStream dso = new DataOutputStream(fos);
  dso.writeBoolean(b);
  dso.writeInt(ab.length);
  for (boolean a: ab)
     dso.writeBoolean(a);
  dso.close();
  fos.close();

  // read
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myconfig.data");
  DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(fis);
  b = ds.readBoolean();
  int len = ds.readInt();
  ab = new boolean[len];
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
     ab[i] = ds.readBoolean();
  ds.close();
  fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> All this code is currently functional, it is just every time I restart
>   the bot all the info stored in the arrays gets deleted ?

When you run your bot program, the data will be stored only in the main memory (RAM) which is temporary during the program execution i.e., data like your arrays, variable, etc.. will be available/reachable only for that run alone.

You need to use either database (preferred) or file systems to store your arrays/data over multiple runs of your bot program.

To start with you can refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) on how Java can connect and make use of database systems using `JDBC` API.

Comment: If I throw this into a collabedit will you be willing to help?